# Count occurences of a category in a Pandas dataframe and enumerate based on groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a df with 2 columns like the one below:

```
    Velocity_in_deg Fix_or_Sac
0         11.206436        Fix
1         36.426933        Fix
2         18.141376        Fix
3         55.304640        Fix
4         43.338237        Sac
5        224.521669        Sac
6        206.720315        Sac
7        245.183128        Sac
8         38.824411        Fix
9         39.164189        Fix
10        17.395825        Fix
11        27.898909        Fix
12        65.819093        Fix
13        13.022764        Fix
14        14.145075        Fix
15       106.541244        Sac
16       228.629117        Sac
17       290.076359        Sac
18       348.790543        Sac
19       359.606755        Sac
20         5.306835        Fix
21         2.940307        Fix
22         8.838205        Fix
23         9.583389        Fix
```

I have used this line of code to create the 'Fix_or_Sac' column:

```
dataset['Fix_or_Sac']=np.where(dataset['Velocity_in_deg']>65, 'Sac','Fix')
```

What I want to do now is to categorize those 'Fix' and 'Sac' into groups based on their sequence,
such that the first occurrence of 'Fix' group is categorized as 'Fix1', the first 'Sac' as 'Sac1', the next group of 'Fix' as 'Fix2' etc., like below:

```
    Velocity_in_deg Fix_or_Sac Group
0         11.206436        Fix  Fix1
1         36.426933        Fix  Fix1
2         18.141376        Fix  Fix1
3         55.304640        Fix  Fix1
4         43.338237        Sac  Sac1
5        224.521669        Sac  Sac1
6        206.720315        Sac  Sac1
7        245.183128        Sac  Sac1
8         38.824411        Fix  Fix2
9         39.164189        Fix  Fix2
10        17.395825        Fix  Fix2
11        27.898909        Fix  Fix2
12        65.819093        Fix  Fix2
13        13.022764        Fix  Fix2
14        14.145075        Fix  Fix2
15       106.541244        Sac  Sac2
16       228.629117        Sac  Sac2
17       290.076359        Sac  Sac2
18       348.790543        Sac  Sac2
19       359.606755        Sac  Sac2
20         5.306835        Fix  Fix3
21         2.940307        Fix  Fix3
22         8.838205        Fix  Fix3
23         9.583389        Fix  Fix3
```

Any ideas on how to do that? The occurrence of Fix and Sac is random so I can't use .iloc[] or sth similar.

Comment: Please don't post images, add your dataframe in `dict` or `text` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

- Compare the current row in the column `Fix_or_Sac` with the previous row to identify the change in sequence
- Calculate cumulative sum to identify the sequences that belong to same group
- Group the sequences on column `Fix_or_Sac` and assign the ordinal rank to each sequence in the same group
- Concat the ranks with the `Fix_or_Sac` column to create `Group`

```
s = df['Fix_or_Sac']

m = s != s.shift()
r = m.cumsum().groupby(s).rank(method='dense')
df['Group'] = s + r.astype(int).astype(str)
```

##### Result

```
    Velocity_in_deg Fix_or_Sac Group
0         11.206436        Fix  Fix1
1         36.426933        Fix  Fix1
2         18.141376        Fix  Fix1
3         55.304640        Fix  Fix1
4         43.338237        Sac  Sac1
5        224.521669        Sac  Sac1
6        206.720315        Sac  Sac1
7        245.183128        Sac  Sac1
8         38.824411        Fix  Fix2
9         39.164189        Fix  Fix2
10        17.395825        Fix  Fix2
11        27.898909        Fix  Fix2
12        65.819093        Fix  Fix2
13        13.022764        Fix  Fix2
14        14.145075        Fix  Fix2
15       106.541244        Sac  Sac2
16       228.629117        Sac  Sac2
17       290.076359        Sac  Sac2
18       348.790543        Sac  Sac2
19       359.606755        Sac  Sac2
20         5.306835        Fix  Fix3
21         2.940307        Fix  Fix3
22         8.838205        Fix  Fix3
23         9.583389        Fix  Fix3
```